# Netty File Server

Tags: java, netty, fileserver

I have been browsing the examples on both an HTTP file server and an uploading server.

I am writting a file server that can do both: send and receive files.  But I am not sure about how to merge the 2 pipelines.
Or maybe I need to modify them depending on the command (upload or get a file).  Even when the docs state that a pipeline cannot be modified for a channel once stablished, I see the "port unification" example does modify it depending on the data.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shg; I think you misunderstood the docs. You can change a pipeline any at any time. Pipelines are also thread safe

Comment: As stated here:  [link](http://static.netty.io/3.5/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html) For each new channel, a new pipeline must be created and attached to the channel. Once attached, the coupling between the channel and the pipeline is permanent; the channel cannot attach another pipeline to it nor detach the current pipeline from it.

Comment: I guess that adding or removing handlers from the pipeline is possible.  Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need a HTTP server and differentiate between HTTP `GET` for downloading files to the client and `POST` to upload files to the server instead of differentiating the types with pipelines. Take a look at [HttpStaticFileServerHandler](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/http/file/HttpStaticFileServerHandler.java) for downloading files with `GET` requests. What you need to adapt are the first lines of `messageReceived`:

```
@Override
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
    HttpRequest request = (HttpRequest) e.getMessage();

    if (request.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.POST)) {
        // receive uploaded file
        return;
    }

    if (request.getMethod() != GET) {
        sendError(ctx, METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
        return;
    }

    ...
```

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I figured I needed to differentiate the request at that point in messageReceived, but as the pipelines to send and upload are different (in the examples),  I was not too sure if they were going to be compatible.  I will experiment and see.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to think of your app as 2 sub-apps in one.

The first sub-app being the file server. You will need to bootstrap and create a pipeline for that as per the [Http file server example](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/http/file/HttpStaticFileServer.java).

The second sub-app being the upload client.  You will need to separately bootstrap and create pipeline for that as per the [http client example](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/http/upload/HttpUploadClient.java).

Comment: If I understood correctly,  you are suggesting to create a regular server and an uploading server, and their corresponding clients?
They should go in 2 different ports also.  
Isn't there a way to create an HTTP file server that can both send and receive files?  Even if that means some dynamic pipeline handling?

Comment: Http servers only responds to requests. If u want to initiate sending a file via http post (as I understood from your question), it is my understanding that u need to implement an http client.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, in fact, I'm not intending to use the browser, it will be a p2p application.  I was wondering if I will need 2 different clients, one for uploading and one for downloading or maybe one will sufice.

Comment: If you are building a client that initiates requests, then 1 will suffice. You only need a server if you intend to listen for and respond to incoming requests.

Comment: I just noticed the existance of **AsyncHttpClient**, which is based on Netty and simplifies a lot the client side development.  I think I will just focus on making one single server with Netty and make the client using this library.